# React/Material UI - Error al cargar datos de celdas en componente Form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Al consumir de una **API** local y cargar los datos en un **DataGrid**, tras hacer clic en cualquier celda independientemente de la fila/columna, se debe tomar los datos de toda la fila (id, name, etc) para cargarlos en un **formulario** para su posterior edición si se desea. Cuando hago **console.log()** para chequear si dichos datos están siendo cargados, no hay problema. Pero, el inconveniente es que el **Form** donde especifico que cada dato se cargue en un **TextField** según una serie de características definidas, se cargan siempre los mismos valores. Ya sea interactuando con el elemento con **ID 1** como con el **ID 9**. Así, con todos los casos. Dicho de otra manera, si hago clic en una celda cuyos valores tiene "ID:1, name: ejemplo, type: x" pero después hago clic en otro cuyo ID es 85, toma los mismos datos que en un principio se han mostrado. Siendo que el console.log() si muestra "ID: 85, name: algo, type: y" pero el form muestra "ID:1, name: ejemplo, type: x".

El código en cuestión es el siguiente:

```
export default function FormEdit(props: any) {
  const { columns, data, typeElement } = props;

  const keys = Object.keys(data);
  let counter = 0;
  const box: any = [];

  if (keys.length > 0) {
    for (let pos = 0; pos < columns.length; pos++) {
      const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(data[keys[pos]]);
      const [content, setData] = React.useState(data[keys[pos]]);

      const changeValue = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setData(e.target.value);
      };

      const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setChecked(!e.target.checked);
      };

      switch (typeElement[keys[counter++]].type) {
        case 'textBox':
          box.push(
            <TextField
              InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
              id="outlined"
              label={columns[pos].headerName}
              value={content}
              onChange={(event) => { setData(event.target.value); }}
            />,
          );
          break;
        case 'checkBox':
          box.push(
            <div>
              <Checkbox
                value={checked}
                onChange={handleChange}
                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'controlled' }}
              />
              active
            </div>,
          );
          break;
        case 'numberBox':
          box.push(
            <TextField
              id="outlined-number"
              label={columns[pos].headerName}
              type="number"
              onChange={changeValue}
              value={content}
              InputLabelProps={{
                shrink: true,
              }}
            />,
          );
          break;
        case 'idBox':
          box.push(
            <TextField
              InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
              id="outlined"
              disabled
              label={columns[pos].headerName}
              value={data[keys[pos]]}
            />,
          );
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '29ch' },
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      {box}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Dejo varias capturas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice varias veces clic en el elemento cuyo ID es 7, para corroborar que los datos están llegando.

Añado también el componente encargado de llamar al formulario:

```
export default function AlertDialogSlide(props: any) {
  const {
    open, onClose, columns, data, typeElement,
  } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={onClose}
        TransitionComponent={Transition}
        keepMounted
        aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
      >
        <DialogActions>
          <Button
            color="error"
            onClick={onClose}
          >
            <CloseIcon />
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-slide-description">
            <FormEdit columns={columns} data={data} typeElement={typeElement} />
          </DialogContentText>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: El problema posiblemente lo tengas en el componente tabla, en la función donde haces click posiblemente no se estén guardando los datos en la variable de la que este formulario lee los datos. Por favor edita la pregunta y añade el código del componente que llama a este formulario para checkearlo

Comment: @Suso ahí realicé el cambio. Aclaro que el Dialog es un componente temporal que estoy utilizando que recibe 3 datos: labels, datos y definiciones que definen a cada uno de ellos (si son textBox, idBox, checkBox, etc). Haciendo console.log() tanto allí como dentro del loop, están llegando todos correctamente